# Mojolicious base URL when running Mojolicious Lite app on Apache under subdirectory

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I'm trying to run a tiny Mojolicious Lite app on Apache (shared hosting) in a subdirectory: `http://www.example.com/mymojoapp/`. And I mostly tried to follow [this guide](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Apache-deployment).

The `mymojoapp` is an actual directory on the server, and app structure as follows:

```
mymojoapp
|- .htaccess
|- app.pl
|- public
|  +- images
|  |  +- ... (image files) ...
|  +- css
|  |  +- ... (css files) ...
|  +- js
|     +- ... (js files) ...
+- templates
   |- layouts
   |  |- index-layout.html.ep
   |  +- other-page-layout.html.ep
   |- index.html.ep
   +- other-page.html.ep
```

`.htaccess` contents:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .pl
Options +ExecCGI

IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.pl/$1 [L]
```

`app.pl` contents (`perlml` is `perl` + paths to user-installed modules, including Mojolicious):

```
#!/usr/bin/perlml

use Mojolicious::Lite;

hook before_dispatch => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->req->url->base(Mojo::URL->new(q{http://www.example.com/mymojoapp/}));
};

get '/' => 'index';

get '/u/:username' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->stash(profile => $self->stash('username'));
} => 'user-profile-page';

app->secrets(['app','secrets']);
app->start;
```

In both `index-layout.html.ep` and `other-page-layout.html.ep` I refer to css (and images) as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= url_for %>/css/styles.css">`. When I access base URL (`http://www.example.com/mymojoapp/`) the page is displayed with proper styling, because the `url_for` gives me  `/mymojoapp/` making path to the stylesheet = `/mymojoapp/css/normalize.css`. But when I access `http://www.example.com/mymojoapp/u/someuser`, the CSS path is `/mymojoapp/u/someuser/css/normalize.css` and styles are not applied.

I feel I'm missing some re-write rules, or it's probably can be fixed in `before_dispatch` hook, but so far I couldn't figure it out.

How can I make sure all pages generated in my app get the correct base URL?

Comment: You should post an answer yourself and name the source. Don't edit the answer into your question. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received the answer over at #mojo in IRC from @jabberwok:

Instead of `<%= url_for %>/css/styles.css` I needed to use `<%= url_for('/css/styles.css') %>`.